# Поиск синтаксического средства выразительности

Tags: синтаксис, лексика, выбор-слов, егэ

> Она выла, рычала, грызла в ярости сетку, но что она могла?!

Какое *синтаксическое* средство выразительности использовано в этом предложении?

Answer (score 3):

Я думаю, что здесь имеет место

> [**Градация**](http://scicenter.online/russkiy-yazyik-scicenter/sintaksicheskie-sredstva-hudojestvennoy-52826.html) — стилистическая фигура, состоящая в таком расположении слов, при котором каждое последующее содержит усиливающееся (реже —
>   уменьшающееся) значение.

Comment: Я согласен. А автор пособия, откуда взят вопрос, нет...

Answer (score 1):

**Она выла, рычала, грызла в ярости сетку, но что она могла?!**

**Здесь нет значения усиления,** поэтому это не градация. Однородный ряд действий имеет о**бщее  выражение протестного чувства**: выла (отчаяние), рычала (злость), грызла (отчаяние, смешанное со злостью, яростью). То есть мы видим **смену чувств:** то отчаяние, то злоба.

Существует выразительное средство **асиндетон (бессоюзие).** Речь идет об однородных рядах с бессоюзной связью, которые придают речи **ритмичность, динамичность, стремительность.**

**Пример:** Швед, русский – колет, рубит, режет. Бой барабанный, клики, скрежет...

Конечно, здесь можно увидеть противопоставление, риторический вопрос, восклицание, но в задании вопрос об одном средстве выразительности (вероятно, главном).

Answer (score 1):

Я думаю, это риторический вопрос и восклицание. Хотя бессоюзие тоже есть.

Comment: Да, в ответе риторическое _восклицание_ (не вопрос почему-то), но в вариантах ответа есть и градация. Скажите, пожалуйста, как вы думаете, нормально ли давать два этих варианта ответа в этом задании?

Comment: Последний-то знак восклицательный, значит, восклицание - верно.Бессоюзия в вариантах ответа ведь нет? Градации я тоже не вижу, если б было : скулила, выла, рычала - тогда бы была.  Вот если бы в ответах были варианты - восклицание и риторический вопрос - тогда, конечно, задание было бы некорректным. А так -вполне. таких заданий много, над которыми нужно долго думать (чтоб жизнь лёгкой не казалась)

Comment: Нет. А почему не градация? Воет — рычит — грызет (металл!). Неужели экспрессивность не возрастает? Выть может и собака весной, рычит — проявляет злость, а грызет клетку — ярость.

Comment: Воет-это тоска, а не ярость, рычит - да, рычит и грызёт клетку - где-то одинаково. Мне вот так видится. Но вообще - вопрос сложный для школьника, конечно, но дело в том, что таких много. Как автор пособия решит - так и верно, и каков ключ на ЕГЭ, дети запросто ошибутся.